# Does the coast of California support a larger population of marine mammals than Maine?

Tags: population-dynamics, marine-biology

Visiting the Maine and California coasts, I've noticed that it is much more common to see marine mammals from the coast in California, including seals, dolphins, and whales. I've been hypothesizing about reasons that this might be the case, and have come up with several ideas.

1. I'm a tourist, not performing a formal population study. Maybe the numbers are similar, but my measurement method is flawed. I've looked up some better numbers in the [NOAA Stock Report](https://www.fisheries.noaa.gov/national/marine-mammal-protection/marine-mammal-stock-assessment-reports-species-stock#pinnipeds---otariids-(eared-seals-or-fur-seals-and-sea-lions)):

   - Seals:

     - Harbor seals, Maine (75,000) vs. California (27,000),
     - California Sea Lions, California (257,000).
   - Whales:

     - Gray Whales, California (27,000)
     - Humpback Whale, Maine (900) vs California (15,000)
   - Dolphins:

     - Common Short-Beaked Dolphin, Maine (170,000) vs California (839,325)

   There are many other species, but these numbers seem to confirm that California has a larger population. Of course, the coast of California is also much larger than the coast of Maine. I'm not sure how to correct for that.
2. Maybe the fishery in the North Atlantic is more overfished. Wikipedia says that 71% of fish capture comes from the Pacific vs 20% from the Atlantic, but that the Pacific has only twice the volume of the Atlantic[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_fisheries). This is much more general than California vs Maine coast, but it suggests that the Pacific has a larger fish population than the Atlantic per volume which could support a larger mammal population.
3. Maybe there are more protected habitats in California. [15% of the south coast region is protected from fishing](http://californiampas.org/mpa-regions/south-coast-region). Whereas in Maine, I was able to find information about *proposed* Marine Protected Areas, but no information about currently protected areas.

**Does the coast of California support a larger population of marine mammals than Maine? If so, what factors support the larger population?**

Comment: You might consider the California coastal current as one possible factor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Current

Comment: Assigning whales to a particular coast seems particularly difficult given the large territories that many (most?) species associate with

Comment: Also why limit to Maine? There's nothing particularly special about Maine vs, say, New Brunswick and Newfoundland and Nova Scotia, besides political boundaries

Comment: @BryanKrause Maine is simply the location where I have visited the coast. If you would prefer to answer for a larger section of the North Atlantic coast, please do.

Comment: @BryanKrause NOAA fishery stock report specifically assigns Humpback Whales in the Gulf of Maine as a "relatively  discrete  subpopulation(s),  fidelity  to  which is determined matrilineally"